# How to explain/understand brackets of applicative functor [[f u1... un]]?

Tags: formal-grammars, lambda-calculus, functional-programming, category-theory, haskell

I am reading article about Applicative Abstract Categorial Grammars http://okmij.org/ftp/gengo/applicative-symantics/AACG.pdf and this article uses brackets [[...]] for action on terms inside applicative functors. These brackets are introduced and somehow explained in "Functional Pearl: Applicative programming with effects" http://strictlypositive.org/IdiomLite.pdf. I understand what applicative functor is and what what is functor generally (both in category theory and Haskell) but I still can not understand the meaning and value of these brackets. I understand the sentence `idiomatic expression [[f x y]] means ηf * ηx * y, or, alternatively, map (f x) y` - that means that `[[F(tau)]]` is sitting inside brackets, but I can not understand the difference between `F(tau)` and `[[F(tau)]]` in brackets (see page 4 of AACG article about context and notation). Also - brackets are not always used with 3 arguments, sometimes there are even on or none arguments!

Do those brackets have meaning, explanation and use in Haskell world? Any explanation - rigorous or not, associative and free-style of not is really appreciated.

http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids contains example:

```
pure (+) <*> Just 3 <*> Just 5
```

Its fine, but what benefit can we get by applying brackets [[]] around this expression, what additional meaning such application created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In it's simplest, original form, $[\![f\ x \ y]\!]$ just means $\eta(f)\circledast x \circledast y$ where $\circledast$ is what Haskell calls `<*>` and $\eta$ is what Haskell calls `pure`. Of course, this is only type correct if $x$, and $y$ have types like $\mathcal{F}(\dots)$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is an applicative functor. If they don't, we can be a bit smarter and automatically use $\eta$/`pure` to "lift" them to that type. From there, the translation can simply be $[\![f\ x_1\dots x_n]\!]\leadsto [\![f]\!]_1\circledast [\![x_1]\!]_1\circledast\cdots\circledast [\![x_n]\!]_1$ where $[\![e]\!]_1$ is either $e$ or $\eta(e)$ depending on the type of $e$. More systematically, $[\![e\ x]\!]\leadsto [\![e]\!]\circledast [\![x]\!]_1$ where $[\![e]\!] = [\![e]\!]_1$ when $e$ is not an application. You can easily imagine a variation that recursively applies the transformation.

The idiom brackets are just for convenience. The example you show of an applicative expression would become `[[3 + 5]]` using idiom brackets which is quite a bit shorter and more readable than `pure (+) <*> pure 3 <*> pure 5` (which is in this case just `pure (3 + 5)` and thus is a fairly trivial case).

I have no idea what you mean by `[[F(tau)]]`. Idiom brackets don't apply to types.

There's a [quasi-quoter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/applicative-quoters-0.1.0.8/docs/Control-Applicative-QQ-Idiom.html) that implements a notation similar to idiom brackets. Idiom brackets are also implemented by the [Strathclyde Haskell Enhancement](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/idiom.html) (SHE) which is made by the person who originally introduced the notation and author of that Functional Pearl, Conor McBride.